# Dynamically toggle split buttons for jQuery mobile listviews

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a mobile app using jquery mobile. I'm using the listview control and so far it works fine.
However I would like to display a split button (http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/listviews/#list-split) but only when a certain button is clicked. The use case is to enable / disable "delete mode", so that the delete icon appears next to the list element only after the button on the toolbar is clicked. I have a more or less working solution which is the following:

```
$('#editmode').live('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('.deletelog').toggle();
$('.deletelog:hidden').closest('li').removeClass("ui-li-has-alt");
$('.deletelog:visible').closest('li').addClass("ui-li-has-alt");
});
```

The problem is, that for the first page load, even if the button is hidden by default:

```
<a href="#" class="deletelog" style="display:none">Delete</a>
```

I still have to add the data attributes data-split-icon and data-split-theme, which makes the first page load look in a way, that there's a space reserved for the button. As you can see from the above code, this is because of the class "data-split-theme". So if I toggle it, then it will disappar for the second toggle.

Is there a better way to realize such a toggling split button?

Thanks!

[image: screenshot 1] [image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

You can show and hide the split buttons by adding a class and manipulating it using jQuery.

To show

```
$('.delete').css('display', 'compact');
```

To hide

```
$('.delete').css('display', 'none');
```

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/2XxJx/

### update

in that case you need to update the css of `ui-li-aside`

```
$('.ui-li-aside ').css('margin-right', '50px');
```

check this live fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/2XxJx/3/

Comment: THanks! Actually I was not enterily clear about my issue in the first post. I have updated it with two screenshots. The problem is that jquery mobile adds a certain spacing when you use data-split-icon data attribute.